# Why are single quotes in my $_POST associative array

Tags: php, foreach

Am writing a code for form and i would like to use PHP associative arrays to get all users input.
Am using a code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="field['Username']" id="username" class="editor" />
```

But when i use a FOREACH statement to loop through the array elements:

```
foreach ($arrInputs as $key => $input){
 echo $key.'<br/>';
}
```

it includes the single quotes in the associative array's index and i get something like:
'Username' (with the quotes) when am echoing the $key in my FOREACH loop..I don't need the single quotes any help?

Comment: Did my answer sort your issue out? Please accept if it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes from your form element, it should just be:

```
<input type="text" name="field[Username]" id="username" class="editor" />
```